# Parsing index lists with construct

Tags: python, construct

Lets say a file format is defined like this:

```
size (uint32)
some_list[size] (uint32)
size_indexes (uint32)
other_list[size_indexes] (uint32)
```

So there is a list `some_list` containing some integers and then there is another list `other_list` containing indexes into `some_list`.

I can parse the whole structure using construct in the following way:

```
from construct import *

fmt = Struct(
        "size" / Int32ul,
        "some_list" / Array(this.size, Int32ul),
        "size_indexes" / Int32ul,
        "other_list" / Array(this.size_indexes, Int32ul),
        )

print(fmt.parse(b"\x02\x00\x00\x00\x23\x42\x23\x42\x13\x37\x13\x37\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00"))
```

which gives me

```
Container: 
    size = 2
    some_list = ListContainer: 
        1109606947
        924006163
    size_indexes = 4
    other_list = ListContainer: 
        1
        1
        0
        1
```

Now that I have parsed the fileformat, what is the preferred way to build a python object out of it? For example, instead of having the other_list contain the indexes, I would like to have it contain the actual values.
Would you wrap another object around it, which has this ability, for example like this:

```
from construct import *

fmt = Struct(
        "size" / Int32ul,
        "some_list" / Array(this.size, Int32ul),
        "size_indexes" / Int32ul,
        "other_list" / Array(this.size_indexes, Int32ul),
        )


class MyFormat:
    def __init__(self, raw):
        self._parsed = fmt.parse(raw)

    @property
    def other_list(self):
        for idx in self._parsed.other_list:
            yield self._parsed.some_list[idx]



container = MyFormat(b"\x02\x00\x00\x00\x23\x42\x23\x42\x13\x37\x13\x37\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00")

print(list(container.other_list))
```

which prints:

```
[924006163, 924006163, 1109606947, 924006163]
```

Is there a better, more preferred way?

Answer (score 0):

In case if `struct` code is not too complicated it is possible to use classes provided by `construct` library. In your case, I would try `IfThenElse` and `RepeatUntil` classes to have only one `struct` to build and parse binary data.

Here is the example:

```
import construct

def repeat_handler( x, lst, ctx):
    lst[-1] = ctx.some_list[x]
    return len(lst) == ctx.size_indexes

my_struct = Struct(
        "s" / Int32ul,
        "some_list" / Array(this.s, Int32ul),
        "size_indexes" / Int32ul,
        "other_list" / construct.IfThenElse(this._parsing,
                                            RepeatUntil(repeat_handler, construct.Int32ul),
                                            Array(this.size_indexes, Int32ul))
        )


built_struct = my_struct.build(dict(s=2, some_list=[1109606947, 924006163], size_indexes=4, other_list=[1, 1, 0, 1]))
print(built_struct)

parsed_struct = my_struct.parse(built_struct)
print(parsed_struct)

assert parsed_struct.other_list == [924006163, 924006163, 1109606947, 924006163]
```